Circumference of ellipse in post-Newtonian metric
The post-Newtonian metric, in harmonic coordinates, is:
$$\tag{1}
\mathrm{d}s^2=-\left(1+\dfrac{2\phi}{c^2}\right)c^2\mathrm{d}t^2 + \left(1-\dfrac{2\phi}{c^2}\right)\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}^2$$
where $\phi=-GM/r_{PN}$, $r_{PN}=|\mathbf{x}|$ and $d\mathbf{x}=\sqrt{\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2+\mathrm{d}z^2}$. I know that in Schwarzschild metric and Schwarzschild coordinates, the circumference of a circle is $C=2\pi r$, while in metric (1) it is $C_{PN}=2\pi r_{PN}\sqrt{1+\dfrac{2GM}{c^2 r_{PN}}}$. So, if one consider the circumference of a circle (e.g. an orbit) as a geometric invariant, one should state that $r_{PN}\simeq r - \dfrac{GM}{c^2}$.
Now, what about if I have an elliptical orbit? Following the reasoning above, I should equate the perimeter of an ellipse computed with the post-Newtonian metric (1) with the perimeter of an ellipse in the Schwarz.  metric (which should be $P=2\pi\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}}$). But how to compute it?
My elliptic orbit is parametrized as: $r=a(1-e\cos{u})$ with $u$ the eccentric anomaly.

When you correct your metric ($ds^2=-(1+2\Phi/c^2)c^2dt^2+(1-2\Phi/c^2)dr^2+r^2 (d\phi^2+sin^2(\theta) d\theta^2)$) you will see that the circumference $C$ is the same in both cases.

It may be worth noting that there is no closed form equation for the perimeter of an ellipse, even in Euclidean geometry
